# How to rebuild flutter Widget on Singleton value change

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to rebuild a stateful widget every time a value in my global Singelton is changed but I'm stumped.

My goal is to rebuild my Cart Icon every time the cartSize is changed throughout my app.

I know I need to send out a notification whenever the Singelton `cartSize` value is changed. and listen for that notification in my stateful widget but how do I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Global Singelton

```
library #######.globals;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GlobalSingleton extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final GlobalSingleton _instance = GlobalSingleton._internal();

  // passes the instantiation to the _instance object
  factory GlobalSingleton() {
    return _instance;
  }

  //initialize variables in here
  GlobalSingleton._internal() {
    cartSize = 0;
  }

  late int cartSize;
}
```

My stateful Widget

```
import 'package:######/globals/globals.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BuildMarketplaceCartIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildMarketplaceCartIcon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BuildMarketplaceCartIcon> createState() =>
      _BuildMarketplaceCartIconState();
}

class _BuildMarketplaceCartIconState extends State<BuildMarketplaceCartIcon> {
  CRUDMarketplaceCart localCartData = CRUDMarketplaceCart();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 72,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                Text(
                  'Cart',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 6,
                  vertical: 2,
                ),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  '${globals.GlobalSingleton().cartSize}',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you a better description, try this: https://pub.dev/packages/property_change_notifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ChangeNotifier` you need to call `notifyListeners` when the value changes. You also need to have your widget listen to the `ChangeNotifier`, so that it knows when to rebuild.

The most common way to go about that is to use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package, which includes the `ChangeNotifierProvider` widget.

Using provider, your code would look something like this:

```dart
class GlobalSingleton extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final GlobalSingleton _instance = GlobalSingleton._internal();

  // passes the instantiation to the _instance object
  factory GlobalSingleton() {
    return _instance;
  }

  //initialize variables in here
  GlobalSingleton._internal() {
    _cartSize = 0;
  }

  late int _cartSize;

  int get cartSize => _cartSize;

  void set cartSize(int newCartSize) {
    _cartSize = newCartSize;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here, we update your singleton so that it will call `notifyListeners()` whenever the cartSize is set.

Next you'll need to update your widget to listen to the changes:

```dart
import 'package:######/globals/globals.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BuildMarketplaceCartIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildMarketplaceCartIcon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BuildMarketplaceCartIcon> createState() =>
      _BuildMarketplaceCartIconState();
}

class _BuildMarketplaceCartIconState extends State<BuildMarketplaceCartIcon> {
  CRUDMarketplaceCart localCartData = CRUDMarketplaceCart();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        width: 72,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                Text(
                  'Cart',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 6,
                  vertical: 2,
                ),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                  value: GlobalSingleton(),
                  child: Consumer<GlobalSingleton>(
                    builder: (context, singleton, child) {
                      return Text(
                        '${singleton.cartSize}',
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I put the `Provider` widget as directly enclosing the `Consumer` widget - however, if you need the singleton's value in more than one place, you can put the `Provider` higher up the widget tree so that it's a common ancestor of any `Consumer` that listens to changes in the singleton.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, makes a lot more sense to me now. The code Worked like a charm too! had to change `builder: (context, singleton)` to `builder: (context, singleton, child)`

Comment: Glad to hear it! And thanks for the heads up on that error, it's fixed now